# The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for android.content

Tags: android, sdk

So, I bought from codecanyon an app and I got this error and don't know how to fix it:

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path and then try building this project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using eclipse. If yes, then check for project properties by right click on project and select property. Check in 'Android' tab whether the project requires any library or not. If yes, then import it to eclipse and give it to project.

Comment: I don't have the Android tab in properties

Comment: When you open the properties, you will find "Android" in the left panel.